# Android Studio "Wrong argument type for formatting Error" in String.format()

Tags: android, lint

```
TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(timeScore);
    i = (int)(gridView.getTime() / 1000L);
    String s = getString(time_score);
    Object aobj[] = new Object[1];
    aobj[0] = Integer.valueOf(i);
    textview.setText(String.format(s, aobj));
```

Getting Error in Android Studio in last conversion aobj

> "Wrong Argument type for formatting argument #1 in time_score: conversion 'd', recevied Object (argument #2 in method call)"

Comment: show initialization of `time_score`

Comment: there is no initialization here, only getting String from resource id

Comment: Pls check or comment the answers.

Comment: Minhtdh answer worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because of `textview.setText(String.format(s, aobj));`

Your string format require integer value but you pass a array to it.

Try this: `textview.setText(String.format(s, i));`

Hope this helps.