# Wrong argument type for formatting argument

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, textview

I use some codes like `temp_out.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃");` to get data from a weather API, but got two lint errors:

> Do not concatenate text displayed with set text. Use resource placeholders only.

> String literals in setText can not be translated. Use Android resources instead.

So i searched here for similar errors on this site and partly found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35053689/13899010,
I used this one because I didn't want using resource String to change the data displayed. Added this to String.xml:
`<string name="blank">%d</string>` then Changed my code to this:

```
temp_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃"));
```

Now i get this error `Wrong argument type for formatting argument '#1' in blank: conversion is 'd', received string (argument #2 in method call)`.
I saw similar question [Android Studio "Wrong argument type for formatting Error" in String.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31553910/13899010) but his solution didn't work for me. How to fix this please?

Comment: I think you can just ignore the first two lines you quoted above before adding a blank string. Since this is just informing you that you should use String resources instead of hard coding strings. But if you want to go with that blank then you should do it like this: <string name="blank">%2$d &#x2103;</string>

Comment: @SlothCoding Now I get: Wrong argument count, format string blank requires 2 but format call supplies 1

Comment: I don't know the type of your response, I guess it is a string then. Just use %s then and it should work.

Comment: I didn't saw the answer below, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure `response.body().getCurrent().getTemp()` returning a int, if its a string use `%s` in string `blank`

you can try one of the following

```
<string name="blank">%d Celsius</string>

//invoking as follows
getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp())
```

```
temp_out.setText("${response.body().getCurrent().getTemp()} Celsius")
```

Comment: Using %s in String blank worked for me, thanks